# How to show another text when select tag opened and closed?

Tags: html, angularjs, html-select

I have simple `select` tag that have some simple options like this:

```
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="1">=</option>
    <option value="2">!=</option>
    <option value="3">^</option>
</select>
```

Now, i want when user click on `select` tag, i show literal texts instead of **=**, **!=**, **^**, i mean **equal**, **not equal** and **start with**, but when user selected one of the values, show the actual text as selected.

I'm using angularjs in this view.

Comment: What do you mean by "show the actual text as selected"?  It is not clear at all what you want the result to be.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Read [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Comment: in che soaliye akhe ???!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the following:

```
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="equals">=</option>
    <option value="not equals">!=</option>
    <option value="start with">^</option>
</select>
```

In your AngularJS code you will have to retrieve the value (which is the most common thing to do) instead of the text between the options tags. That way you can still show the symbols between the `<option></option>` but the value is hidden in the option tags with the actual word you want set as a value of the options

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of objects for your dropdown values in your controller:

```
$scope.options=[
 {
  Description:"=", 
  Value:"equals"
 },
 {
  Description:"!=", 
  Value:"not equals"
 },
 {
  Description:"^", 
  Value:"start with"
 }
];
```

and in your html, you could loop through your options object, only display "Description" of your objects in the select options, and once an option is selected, it will be assigned to your ng-model:

```
<select ng-model="mySelect" ng-options="o as o.Description for o in options" >
</select>
<div>
  {{mySelect.Value}}
</div>
```

Take a look at this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xnzp78ju/